# handling different required package versions

Tags: python

I (thankfully) never ran into this before, and (sadly) just did.

My app now imports 2 packages, which each import the `requests` library.  The two authors have pegged the version of `requests` to different versions.  One wants 2.1.0 , the other wants 2.3.0.

Automated tests appear to pass on both.  My app appears to function perfectly on both.

My app won't start, however, because of the requirements.  From what I can understand on my development environment, it's because of the version number being pegged in a requirements.txt file.   [ In dev we have PasteDeploy + Waitress, an exception is raised in PasteDeploy; in production we have uwsgi ]

The only ways I can think of handling this, is to:

- fork the projects
- change the system to not use zipped eggs, and run a patch.

both are going to be a hassle to maintain, and add a lot of complexity to the build/deploy process.

does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: What about forking the first project to require `>= 2.1.0` and then submitting that upstream to see if they'll accept it? Really, unless there's a serious bug in requests 2.2.0 (and a breaking API change would be a serious bug according to their versioning policy) nobody should be doing this. That should only be a hassle to maintain for a short time (especially if you're willing to stick with your fork without updates until upstream changes).

Comment: There is one more horrible option that may apply: If you don't actually need to import both packages in the same processes, you could have two virtual environments (or even two completely independent Python installs), with `requests` 2.1.0 and the package that needs it and your code that needs that package in one, and 2.3.0 etc. in the other, communicating through pipes or whatever IPC makes sense. I've done (the more extreme version of) this to use a library that hadn't been updated to Python 2.6 yet with one that needed 2.6. It sucked, but it worked.

Comment: I had already filed tickets with both projects for better support of `requests`, and noted the packages which pass.  The first project has rejected patches that do >=2.1.0 because of past API breaking changes, but I suggested using a window approach `>=2.1.0,<=2.3.0` to give better flexibility.  I don't like their policy, and I think it causes more issues than it solves.  The second project works on the entire 2.0 branch; 2.3.0 seemed to be the current version when they upgraded from the 1.x series.

Comment: I was actually considering your second "horrible" option.  I was just too scared to admit it.

Comment: One of the package maintainers was open to expanding the requirements, so I forked and updated their requirements and travis config.  In the meantime, I wrote a fabric script to uninstall the packages, reinstall unzipped, and patch one.

Comment: As I said, I've actually done the horrible option; sometimes the last resort is the only choice you have. But if the only thing stopping both libraries from working with 2.1.0 or 2.3.0 is the requirements, then yeah, I think you're making the right choice changing that in a fork and submitting it upstream. If it works out, you might want to post and accept your own answer. (Or, if you don't think it'll help other people, delete your question, but I think it might be helpful.)

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for a few more days, in case there is better insight out there.  I doubt there is, but we can hope!

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple of options these are the only ones I can think of:

1. fork (sorry but this may be the easiest/ quickest),
2. wait for a new version for the older package, or
3. change it to not use zipped eggs (I don't really understand this though).
4. [EDIT] could you potentially trick one into thinking that it is using its version. I don't know the specifics, but from my understanding you could use a virtual machine.

There could be others that I don't know (it actually probable) but that is all I could think of hopefully you find a solution though!

Comment: So you're suggesting that he do one of the ideas that he raised in his question? What does that add to what he already knows?